# How to ignore one of the fields from a Joi schema?

Tags: javascript, joi

I have the following Joi schema for a User:

```js
const userRules = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp('^[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúãõÃÕâêôÂÊÔ ]+$')).required(),
    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
    password: Joi.string().min(8).max(40).required()
});
```

But for authentication purposes, I only want to validate `email` and `password`, ignoring `name`. Is it possible to do this without having to create a different schema?

Answer (score 6):

This will ignore `name`:

```
const userRules = Joi.object({
    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
    password: Joi.string().min(8).max(40).required()
})
.options({allowUnknown: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Joi.fork()` to create a derived schema from a base one.

```js
const userRules = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp('^[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúãõÃÕâêôÂÊÔ ]+$')).required(),
    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
    password: Joi.string().min(8).max(40).required()
});
const authSchema = userRules.fork(['name'], (schema) => schema.optional())
```

Now, in `authSchema`, the `name` attribute is optional and can be ignored.